# buildin compareTo: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections

i am currently struggling to Sort a Collection in Java. I get the error message 'Comparison method violates its General contract'. I also understand this error message, but i am (mostly) using the buildin compareTo-Method of the type Long. So I don't know, in which case the sort Method is still violating the contract. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DataAge another) {
    if(this == null || another == null)
        return 0;

    Long a = new Long(this.getAge());
    Long b = new Long(another.getAge());
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

And here the error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)

at dd.GMAAnalyzer.sortData(Analyzer.java:158)
```

Comment: Note: `this == null` is always false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `null`s are allowed, the logic of your method is incorrect, because `null` compares equal to anything. This is wrong, because it will compare equal to multiple things that are not equal among themselves, thus breaking the transitivity.

To fix this problem, decide if `null`s should sort ahead or at the back of other numbers, and add a separate `null` comparison (`this` cannot be equal to `null`, so you do not need a comparison for it).

```
if(another == null)
    return 1; // If you want nulls in the back, return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Note that `null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` even though `e.equals(null)` returns false.

Also, you don't need to create `Long` instances:

```
return Long.compare(this.getAge(), another.getAge());
```